# Visualforce CommandButton Open in Existing Window

Tags: visualforce, commandbutton

I am trying to overwrite the standard buttons on a standard object with an embedded VF page.  The reason for this is that I want a custom button to be conditionally rendered based upon a field in the record.  I get the buttons to display, but when I click them they open within the detail page of the record.  How do I get them to open over the existing page like standard buttons normally do?

```
<apex:page standardController="Contract" >
<apex:form >
<div style="text-align: center">
    <apex:commandButton value="Edit" action="{!Edit}"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!Delete}"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Clone" action="{!URLFOR($Action.Contract.Clone,Contract.id)}"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Amend" OnClick="window.open('/apex.VF_Quote');"/>
</div>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Can you clarify - [within the detail page]? With your current implementation, it should open in a new window, is that not happening right now? And can you clarify, what do you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add target to the parent tag, as you can see the following code i have added to the `<apex:form>`, i have tested and it's working

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" >
<apex:form target="_parent" >
<div style="text-align: center">
<apex:commandButton value="Edit" action="{!Edit}" />
<apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!Delete}"/>
</div>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a target for your custom buttons like below:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Amend" OnClick="window.open('/apex.VF_Quote');" target="_self"/>
```

> Following are the options for target:
>
> - _blank : Opens the linked document in a new window or tab
> - _self    : Opens the linked document in the same frame as it was clicked (this is default)
> - _parent  : Opens the linked document in the parent frame
> - _top       : Opens the linked document in the full body of the window

Comment: I get an error message that target is an unsupported attribute.

Comment: `target` is not a supported attribute for `apex:commandButton`